# Adding result of Axios call to State

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

This is a very basic question but I'm not getting anywhere...

Doing a simple shopping cart with Vue and Vuex.  I had the products hard-coded in the state but now I'm trying to do an axios call and add that result to the state.  I have the axios function and I'm trying to load the function and have the JSON result appended to the array `all`.

How do I put the result of loadItems() into the `all` array?  Thank you

EDIT:  I have updated with my entire vuex file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
import * as types from './mutation-types'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// axios call
const api = {
  loadItems() {

    // Init variables
    var self = this
    var app_id = "asdfasf";
    var app_key = "asdfasfaf";
    this.items = []
    axios.get(
      "https://api.airtable.com/v0/"+app_id+"/Products",
      { 
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer "+app_key } 
      }
    ).then(function(response){
      self.items = response.data.records.map((item)=>{
        return {
            id: item.id,
            ...item.fields
        }
      })
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
}

// initial state
const state = {
  added: [],
  all: []
}

// getters
const getters = {
    allProducts: state => state.all, // would need action/mutation if data fetched async
    getNumberOfProducts: state => (state.all) ? state.all.length : 0,
    cartProducts: state => {
        return state.added.map(({ id, quantity }) => {
            const product = state.all.find(p => p.id === id)

            return {
                name: product.name,
                price: product.price,
                quantity
            }
        })
    }
}

// actions
const actions = {
    addToCart({ commit }, product){
        commit(types.ADD_TO_CART, {
            id: product.id
        })
    },
    removeFromCart({ commit }, product){
        commit(types.REMOVE_FROM_CART, {
            id: product.id
        })
    }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {

    [types.ADD_TO_CART] (state, { id }) {
        const record = state.added.find(p => p.id === id)

        if (!record) {
          state.added.push({
            id,
            quantity: 1
          })
        } else {
          record.quantity++
        }
      },
    [types.REMOVE_FROM_CART] (state, { id }) {
        const record = state.added.find(p => p.id === id)

        if (!record) {
          state.added.pop({
            id,
            quantity: 1
          })
        } else {
          record.quantity--
        }
      },
}

// one store for entire application
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    strict: debug,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
})
```

Comment: Are you using actions to call loadItems or directly from view?. Do you have your vuex in store.js?

Comment: This is within my index.js file within store.  When I look at it, I dont know if I'm actually calling loadItems.  I dont see the JSON in the console.

Comment: As you can see here https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html you need to have all your vuex state/getters/mutations/actions in same Vuex.store to call between them. Try to add your loadItems as actions and states in state. After that you can call state between getters (or directly but is a bad practice) with state.yourNameState = Anything. Try to read this: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html Your actual vuex config is not right.

Comment: Thanks NBlack, I have updated my post with my entire file.  Reading the page about actions.  Thanks

Comment: I've attached a little approach of how your vuex have to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little approach to your goal:

You can access with state.yourStateNameVariable or better make a getter and commit to get/set value from that state.

Observations:
[types.ADD_TO_CART] is not a good name for commit, maybe addToCart and removeFromCart?

You dont need to save in items your response from axios, you can directly after resolve send to all state with state.all = yourdata or better, add mutation

```
setAllData({ state }, data){
    state.all = data
}
```

I do not fixed all your code but here you are an approach:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
import * as types from './mutation-types'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default new Vuex.Store({
state:{
    added: [],
  all: [
    {
      id: 'cc919e21-ae5b-5e1f-d023-c40ee669520c',
      name: 'COBOL 101 vintage',
      description: 'Learn COBOL with this vintage programming book',
      price: 399
    },
    {
      id: 'bcd755a6-9a19-94e1-0a5d-426c0303454f',
      name: 'Sharp C2719 curved TV',
      description: 'Watch TV like never before with the brand new curved screen technology',
      price: 1995
    },
    {
      id: '727026b7-7f2f-c5a0-ace9-cc227e686b8e',
      name: 'Remmington X mechanical keyboard',
      description: 'Excellent for gaming and typing, this Remmington X keyboard ' +
        'features tactile, clicky switches for speed and accuracy',
      price: 595
    }
  ]
},
getters: {
 allProducts: state => state.all, // would need action/mutation if data fetched async
    getNumberOfProducts: state => (state.all) ? state.all.length : 0,
    cartProducts: state => {
        return state.added.map(({ id, quantity }) => {
            const product = state.all.find(p => p.id === id)

            return {
                name: product.name,
                price: product.price,
                quantity
            }
        })
    }
},
mutations: {
setAllData({ state }, data){
    state.all = data
},
 [types.ADD_TO_CART] ({ state }, id) {
        const record = state.added.find(p => p.id === id)

        if (!record) {
          state.added.push({
            id,
            quantity: 1
          })
        } else {
          record.quantity++
        }
      },
    [types.REMOVE_FROM_CART] ({ state }, id) {
        const record = state.added.find(p => p.id === id)

        if (!record) {
          state.added.pop({
            id,
            quantity: 1
          })
        } else {
          record.quantity--
        }
      }
},
actions:{
  loadItems({getters, commit}, somethingYouReceive) {

    // Init variables
    var self = this
    var app_id = "adsfasfasgag";
    var app_key = "agasdgagasgasg";
    this.items = []
    axios.get(
      "https://api.airtable.com/v0/"+app_id+"/Products",
      { 
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer "+app_key } 
      }
    ).then(function(response){
      commit('setAllData',response.data.records.map((item)=>{
        return {
            id: item.id,
            ...item.fields
        }
      })
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error)
    })
  },
   addToCart({ commit }, product){
        commit(types.ADD_TO_CART, {
            id: product.id
        })
    },
    removeFromCart({ commit }, product){
        commit(types.REMOVE_FROM_CART, {
            id: product.id
        })
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @NBlack still working on it!  If I change ADD_TO_CART to addToCart (here and in my mutation-types.js file), will it cause any conflicts with the addToCart method?  When I copied the code above I still wasn't seeing the JSON in my console sources.  I see the action is available, but should it not be called in some way?  Is this easier if my original `all` array was just empty?

Comment: I put the setAllData within getters

Comment: Now I'm just trying to receive the JSON and load it into the empty array.  I thought this would be easy :)

Comment: Your addToCart method from vuex is called with this.$store.commit(‘addToCart’, product) in your component versus this.addToCart() that is a method of your component ;). When you receive in axios.then... you have to set commit(‘yourmethodToSetAllValue’, res....) and thats it!

Im sure you will got it soon!

Comment: To receive json you have to call actions from your component with this.$store.dispatch(‘loadItem’) and if want to wait until finish to do something (then...), use promises, you need to transform in promise with return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>....)
Im sure you will got it soon!

Comment: Thanks NBlack, will take a break.  I think I'm confusing myself.  I noticed the add to cart method wasn't working with your changes, thanks for the update.  I will give it a shot again in the morning!  Have a great night/day

Comment: I was getting an error last: `Syntax Error: SyntaxError: /src/store/index.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (99:4)

   97 |         }
   98 |       })
>  99 |     }).catch(function(error){
      |     ^
  100 |       console.log(error)
  101 |     })
  102 |   },


 @ ./src/main.js 9:0-28 15:9-14
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js`

Comment: In my component, I simply had two methods: `  methods: mapActions([
 'addToCart',
 'removeFromCart'
  ])` and for the click event: `@click='addToCart(product)'`

Comment: I keep getting an error with the loadItems in actions.  It doesn't like the `}).catch(function(error){` line.  I think I understand the new way I'll call to action in the component now.